# Is there any possible way for my ISP to block specifically WiFi enabled routers?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

I've a FTTH connection ([I've this intermediate device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_media_converter)) , I have both [this(1)](https://www.tp-link.com/us/home-networking/wifi-router/archer-c1200/)  and [this(2)](https://www.linksys.com/dk/p/P-E1200/) WiFi enabled routers.

I mainly use the first one(1). My ISP provided manual setup goes below :

```
IP ADDR :   172.22.218.27
SUBNET  :   255.255.255.128
GATEWAY :   172.22.218.1

DNS1    :   172.16.0.1
DNS2    :   8.8.8.8
```

Some hours ago the network was down for 12-13 hours and they said it was for a server upgrade.

That's fine. But, the problem is when the network came back both of my routers stopped working. When I put the same IPV4 setup on my laptop by directly connecting to the LAN, the internet works, but when I connect through my routers, I get *request timeouts*.

I tried to revert back to original firmware from DDWRT of my 2nd router. Tried resetting and rebooting 10 times but no luck.

I even cloned the MAC of my laptop and stopped the NTP Client in router settings.

AFAIK, our ISP support hate routers for a reason. **But, is there any way that they can block routers ?!?**

Comment: You'll probably have to speak to your ISP. No-one else can analyse the traffic, or know what they block or allow.

Comment: I already have a Fiber to LAN converter, which provides LAN access. I just need to configure the device in which I want to use internet. That's it.

The same setup - routers don't work - laptops/desktops do. And after certain ISP System upgrade.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100157/discussion-between-csgo-and-tetsujin).

Comment: @Tetsujin https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_media_converter

Comment: The answer to the direct question is yes.  If it has a MAC address then your ISP has the ability to deny service to it.  There's no way for anyone except your ISP to say that is happening or for what reason it may/may not be happening.

Comment: It is unclear: are you entering the above IP address for the router's WAN or LAN? From what I can tell, your "fiber to LAN" device is the WAN.

Comment: @Tetsujin except OP said he cloned the MAC

Comment: @davidgo - [sorry, I binned my last comment before I realised this…] OP said the **laptop** MAC was cloned - which is completely irrelevant as it wouldn't pass the border anyway. The **router** MAC is the relevant datum.

Comment: @tetsujin - partially disagree - the laptop apparently worked when plugged in directly, so cloning it us a reasonable thing to do. But come to think of it, if the WAN has the laptop MAC address, and the laptop is plugged into the LAN this could break things for the laptop as the router could route traffic for laptop to WAN interface.

Comment: If the laptop works when directly connected, then the ISP have a functional 'domestic' router capability on the other end of that line… & that's something I've never worked with [it doesn't ever happen in the UK] so I'll leave you to it ;)

Comment: @davidgo Nope, to avoid IP conflict when I cloned laptop mac, instead of connecting laptop, I connected desktop with the router... Point to be mentioned, desktop alone with configuration works just like laptop - no problem. 

|| Today I took my two friend's router - TP-Link Archer C55 & Mi Router 3C | Connected the same way laptop/desktop is connected with the same configuration.... and the same result... routers dont work.

Answer (score 0):

"Blocking Routers" while not affecting other directly connected devices is unlikely. (They would need to have entry into the routers, or run probes to fingerprint them if you have cloned the WAN address).

I wonder if their upgrades have created an MTU issue - maybe they have been implementin MPLS or a similar technology.   **what do ping and trace route show?** (they would not be affected if its an MTU issue as the packets are small)

BTW your "ISP" is (a) not really an ISP and (b) incompetent. They should not be using the 172.22 block to connect clients as this is an RFC1918 address. It is not designed for this purpose (but can technically work). It is conceivable (but somewhat unlikely) that your router is doing egress/ingress filtering on this IP range because it should not appear on an Internet WAN connection. Its also conceivable that this conflicts with your LAN subnet - although if you have not changed IP addresses recently this obviously won't be the problem.

Another - also unlikely possibility is that your ISP is using pppoe (in which case the 172 address is actually OK). If that's the case then you additionally need the pppoe username and password configured in your router - and that is what would be giving you your Internet (over a PPP tunnel). That said if PPPoE was needed your laptop would not work when directly plugged in. **are you sure your laptop had a connection and was not just using cached data?**

Comment: Yes, my ISP is not really an ISP, they buy internet from actual ISP and sell the data keeping profit. 


    1. The laptop had proper internet connection.
2. The connection is not PPPoE


All things work perfectly ( ping/traceroute ) in laptop/desktop but not in routers

Comment: Today I took my two friend's router - TP-Link Archer C55 & Mi Router 3C | Connected the same way laptop/desktop is connected with the same configuration.... and the same result.

Comment: I'm really confused that how specially routers aren't working?